# communication between PHP and android

Tags: php, android

I am developing an android app in which user send data to PHP server.For this, i am using rest web service, i am sending heavy data which take almost 2 minutes to execute and i want when user send data to PHP server, server should send back success message to user and server perform execution of data in separate thread.How is it possible?

Comment: Use json with `asynctask`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to perform heavy operations without blocking the UI thread.

I believe this code should be enough to get you started.

```
private class MyHeavyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
    // Perform initialization here. 
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        // Showing progress dialog
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyActivity.this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
        progressDialog.show();
    }

    // If an error is occured executing doInBackground()
    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        // Show an alert box.
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);

        builder.setCancelable(false)
               .setTitle("Error!")
               .setMessage("Error in executing your command.")
               .setInverseBackgroundForced(true)
               .setPositiveButton("Dismiss", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        if(!isCancelled()) {
            // Perform heavy lifting here.
        }
        return true;
    }

    // After the request's performed. Here, hide the dialog boxes, inflate lists, etc.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (progressDialog.isShowing())
            progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```

You can simply call the AsyncTask via the following line of code:

```
new MyHeavyTask().execute();
```

Hope it helps with your problem.

Comment: thanks i know that solution but give me server side solution how server send user success message and perform heavy work in separate thread.

Comment: PHP, to its core, is a single-threaded scripting language. Unless you're relying on a third-party solution, executing multiple threads solely on PHP is impossible.
I don't understand, why do you even want multi-threaded solution, anyway.

Comment: basically i have a list of 700 lat lng and i want to get a area names against those lat lng using geo coder class problem is that when i get area names my app take too much time to compute it thats why i want to compute it on server side not on mobile side

Comment: Where do you have the list? If it is already on the mobile side, doing so on server-side would mean extra seconds added to making request to the server and getting a response back in opposed to performing the operation on the app.
I still don't understand why you asked the original question, i.e. the need for a thread to perform this activity.

Comment: THATS WHY USER SEND LIST TO SERVER AND SRVER GIVE SUCCESS MESSAGE AND GECODE THE LIST IN SEPARATE THREAD.